# Sorting the output text file in hadoop, is there a way to view the output without sorting it? or using different sorting method?

Tags: sorting, hadoop, output, word-count

So basically I used mapreduce for wordcount for a text file I've saved in hadoop, now I want to the view output.

Currently this is the only command I've seen online:

```
bin/hadoop fs -cat output/part-r-00000 | sort -k 2 -n -r | less
```

So far I'm just confused by this command, is it just sort the output? can I view the output without sorting it?

Is this command sorting the wordcount display everything in alphabetical order otherwise? Is there any other way you would recommend to sort the saved the text fie, a novel?

Also can I just view the outputfile of wordcount without sorting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I view the output without sorting it?

Just `-cat` it

```
bin/hadoop fs -cat output/part-r-00000 | less
```

Or copy the output file to the Local FS from HDFS and use it

```
bin/hadoop fs -get output/part-r-00000  /tmp/output
```

> Is this command sorting the wordcount display everything in
>   alphabetical order otherwise?

`sort -k 2 -n -r`: Sort the 2nd column (`-k 2`) numerically (`-n`) in reverse (`-r`) order.

Assuming the second column contains the count, this would sort the words from most number of occurrences to the least. As for the different way of sorting, I feel this is the better one. If you want to sort the content alphabetically, just use `sort`. Refer [sort manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sort).

Comment: `-cat` just prints the content of the HDFS file to stdout. Running the `-cat` command multiple times will not change the source.

Comment: Oh I meant is 1) Do you recommend any other way to sort the output of word count besides i posted

Comment: 2) Also is there on ubuntu to scroll down the last page of output really fast? my wordcount output is way too too long

Comment: 1) The one you have already posted is better. 2) Pipe the `-cat` output to  `| less`. See updated answer.

Comment: Sir how do I "pipe" it, right now the cat process take so long, then again it is a very large text file

Comment: Sir i didnt see any changes?